# Issue with KafkaSpout.class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have used KafkaSpout class of the storm.kafka package to fetch messages from the kafka topic. I could see around 340 tuples were emitted per second. C I did increase no of threads  for parallellism but there is no difference in the count.ould you please advise me on how to increase the no of messages/tuples emitted per second by kafkaSpout?

Thanks,
Bhaskar.

Comment: Are you having any failed number of tuples ?

Comment: There were no failed tuples. I have increased the fetch size from default to 5 MB, 10 MB like that.

Comment: Are you sure the rate messages are being produced is higher than 340? How many partitions does your kafka topic has? You can (should) use one worker per partition

Comment: I have been testing with only one partition and two workers. I have just added the following config parameters.                                                                                                               properties.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 2);
  properties.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 5);
   properties.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_ACKER_EXECUTORS, 4); with this I could see around 1500 msgs per sec were processed. Please suggest  how I can increase the rate to  reach 10000  msgs per sec?

Comment: Try increasing TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING to a greater value.
As per docs: 

TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING
The maximum number of tuples that can be pending on a spout task at any given time. This config applies to individual tasks, not to spouts or topologies as a whole. A pending tuple is one that has been emitted from a spout but has not been acked or failed yet. Note that this config parameter has no effect for unreliable spouts that don't tag their tuples with a message id.


Increase TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING to about 1000 and try.

Comment: Is the Spout pending only parameter that enhance the performance? or are there any other parameters that we can change from default to  increase the rate?

Comment: Also what happens if increase the TOPOLOGY_ACKER_EXECUTORS?